# select accounts that not have more than 2 roles in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 table, I want select all account have role User only, that mean if account have both role Admin and User then not select them.

*I got stuck, many thanks if someone can help me*

---

**Account:**
[image]

---

**Role:**
[image]

---

**Account_Role:** [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create data:

```
DECLARE @account TABLE (AccountId INT, Username NVARCHAR(255), Password NVARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @role TABLE (Id INT, Role NVARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @account_role TABLE (AccountId INT, RoleId INT)

INSERT INTO @account VALUES (1, 'admin', null), (2, 'user1', null), (3, 'user2', null)
INSERT INTO @role VALUES (1, 'Admin'), (2, 'User')
INSERT INTO @account_role VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)
```

Select all accounts that have roleId 2 but not accounts that have roleId 1:

```
SELECT a.* FROM @account a
INNER JOIN @account_role ar ON ar.AccountId = a.AccountId
INNER JOIN @role r ON ar.RoleId = r.Id
WHERE r.Id = 2
  AND a.AccountId NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM @account_role WHERE RoleId = 1)
```

Comment: this answer is easier to understand for me

Answer (score 4):

You can use aggregation:

```
select accountid
from accountrole ar join
     role r
     on ar.roleid = r.id
group by accountid
having count(*) = 1 and min(r.role) = 'User';
```

Comment: You are my life saver 

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inner join`, `exists` and closure as follow:

```
SELECT AccountID, Username, Password
FROM Account A JOIN Account_Role AR
ON A.AccountID = AR.AccountID
JOIN Role R
ON R.RoleID = AR.RoleID
WHERE R.Role = 'User'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Accout_Role AR2, Role R2
    WHERE AR2.RoleID = R2.RoleID 
    AND A.AccountID = AR2.AccountID
    AND R2.Role <> 'User'
);
```